# sending signal to a blocked thread with a timer

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, signals

I am running two processes (Process A and B) on the same core. Process B is multithreaded in which one thread is sending Signal to the next thread to wake it and start its work. At a time, only one thread of process B can run on the common core.

```
**//Process A** 
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct timeval tval_result;
    cpu_set_t my_set;        
    CPU_ZERO(&my_set);       
    CPU_SET(2, &my_set);     
    sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &my_set);
    long int loopNum;
    while(1)
    {
        gettimeofday(&tval_result, NULL);
            printf("Dummy Time elapsed: %ld.%06ld\n", (long int)tval_result.tv_sec, (long int)tval_result.tv_usec);
        //for(loopNum = 1; loopNum <= 100000; loopNum++);
            //printf("Dummy!!! # \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Following is the code of Process B.

```
//Import 
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 100

//global variables

pthread_cond_t      condA[NUM_THREADS+1]  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t      condB  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t     mutex  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
int state = 0;

void *threadA(void *data_)
{
    int i = 0, rValue;
    long int loopNum;

    int turn = (intptr_t)data_;

    struct timeval tval_result;
    while(1)
    {
        cpu_set_t my_set;        
        CPU_ZERO(&my_set);       
        CPU_SET(2, &my_set);     
        sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &my_set);
        /* Wait for state A */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        // while (state != STATE_A)
        if(state != turn)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&condA[turn], &mutex);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        //do stuff
        gettimeofday(&tval_result, NULL);
        printf("Time elapsed: %ld.%06ld\n", (long int)tval_result.tv_sec, (long int)tval_result.tv_usec);
        //for(loopNum = 1; loopNum <= 10000000000; loopNum++);
        //printf("Hello Thread # %d\n", turn);

        /* Set state TRUE for next thread */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        state = (state +1)%NUM_THREADS;
        pthread_cond_signal(&condA[state]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int data = 0;
    int err;

    while(data < NUM_THREADS)
    {
        //create our threads
        err = pthread_create(&tid[data], NULL, threadA, (void *)(intptr_t)data);
        if(err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        else
            printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");

        data++;
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

I want to interleave the execution of process B in between threads of Process A for a very short duration (less than 1 microseconds). So, when thread i of process B finishes its work it'll send the signal to the next thread i+1 and in between, I want process A to come. This should be repeated for the rest of the course of execution.

When I am running above programs, process A is not able to come in between threads of the Process B. Is there any mechanism by which I can send signal with some timer so that signal does not reach the next thread immediately (and hence Process A comes for some time between two consecutive threads.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you can force the Linux scheduler at that level.
You'll have to "signal" process A and then let it "signal" the other B thread.

But to "signal" may be a user space mechanism like spinning on a variable in shared memory.

I'd suggest you first try it with normal signals (going through the kernel) and see is the latency good enough. Only if it's too long, go play with spinning in user space.

Don't expect all that to work *always* under 1us. You'll probably get lots of jitter will have to move processes away from that core to reduce it, regardless of spinning or using kernel signalling.

For kernel signalling you may also use sockets, pipes, futexes,...

Now my question is, if you're running all that on one core, as you said, why not run it as a single thread - Just have one thread call B1, then A, then B2?

Comment: Thanks @BitWhistler for your pertinent notes and suggestions. Yes, there is no way to send Signal with a timer. I could use one thread only but I want process A to get pre-empted every time Process B awake. So, if it will be multithreaded, it's virtual runtime will be increasing very slowly in comparison to that of Process A and hence it'll get CPU as soon as it awake (pre-empting Process A).